# how will I change the state of a checkbox that is dependent on another checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two checkboxes, if one of them is checked (true) the other one should be unchecked(false).

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    Checked: {
      Score: 1,
      Selected: true
    },
    Unchecked: {
      Score: 0,
      Selected: false
    }
  });
  const handleChecked = (e) => {
    if (input.Unchecked.Selected) {
      setInput({
        ...input,
        Checked: {
          ...input.Checked,
          Selected: false
        }
      });
    } else {
      setInput({
        ...input,
        Checked: {
          ...input.Checked,
          Selected: e.target.checked
        }
      });
    }
  };
  const handleUnchecked = (e) => {
    if (input.Checked.Selected) {
      setInput({
        ...input,
        Unchecked: {
          ...input.Unchecked,
          Selected: false
        }
      });
    } else {
      setInput({
        ...input,
        Unchecked: {
          ...input.Unchecked,
          Selected: e.target.checked
        }
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Space>
        <Checkbox
          checked={input.Checked.Selected}
          onChange={(e) => handleChecked}
        >
          Checked
        </Checkbox>
        <Checkbox
          checked={input.Unchecked.Selected}
          onChange={(e) => handleUnchecked}
        >
          Unchecked
        </Checkbox>
      </Space>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-pond-zx3vug?file=/src/App.js

The code doesn't change the state onclick.
If suppose the first checkbox (Checked) is true then the second checkbox should be false. Incase, the user clicks on the second checkbox, the second checkbox should be true and should make the first checkbox false. (i.e) both of the checkboxes can't be true.
But both the checkboxes can be false.

Comment: Usually, you would use radio buttons for this sort of thing and not checkboxes (with a way to clear your selection, eg: a "none" option or a button to clear your selection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 2 functions to handle the same. You can toggle the value when it's clicked.  check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-pond-0rczi5?file=/src/App.js)

Issue with your code: You are not calling function

```
onChange={handleChecked}
```

Better Solution:

```
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    Checked: {
      Score: 1,
      Selected: true
    },
    Unchecked: {
      Score: 0,
      Selected: false
    }
  });
  const handleChecked = (e) => {
    setInput((input) => ({
      ...input,
      Checked: {
        ...input.Checked,
        Selected: !input.Checked.Selected
      },
      Unchecked: {
        ...input.Unchecked,
        Selected: !input.Unchecked.Selected
      }
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Space>
        <Checkbox checked={input.Checked.Selected} onChange={handleChecked}>
          Checked
        </Checkbox>
        <Checkbox checked={input.Unchecked.Selected} onChange={handleChecked}>
          Unchecked
        </Checkbox>
      </Space>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining state for checkboxes can be simplified. For 2 checkboxes it's probably ok, however if you need to construct checkboxes from json array then you will run into problem.

So I will define the state like this, array of objects consisting all metadata regarding each checkbox control.

```
 const [input, setInput] = useState([
    { name: "chkbox1", Score: 1, Selected: true },
    { name: "chkbox2", Score: 0, Selected: false }
  ]);
```

so in jsx you have to adopt the change accordingly, currently for your example it would be like this, however again this could be in `.map` function as iterable controls.

```
<Checkbox
          name="chkbox1"
          checked={input[0].Selected}
          onChange={handleChecked}
        >
          Checked
</Checkbox>
<Checkbox
          name="chkbox2"
          checked={input[1].Selected}
          onChange={handleChecked}
        >
          Unchecked
</Checkbox>
```

Finally in `handleChecked` event, you can find other checkbox which is not checked and toggle that accordingly. You can do it even without name, but just by passing index.

```
const handleChecked = (e) => {    
    let temp = [...input];
    let otherCheckboxIndex = temp.findIndex((obj => obj.name !== e.target.name));
    let thisCheckboxIndex = temp.findIndex((obj => obj.name === e.target.name));       
    temp[otherCheckboxIndex].Selected = !e.target.checked;
    temp[thisCheckboxIndex].Selected = e.target.checked;
    setInput(temp);
};
```

See here [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-frog-l05q68?file=/src/App.js).